# "isojounp.exe" Error message in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus

My windows 7 is constantly prompting with an alert box saying "isojounp.exe quit working. Windows is looking for a solution to solve the problem".

I've tried searching for "isojounp.exe" in the entire web and didn't found anything about it. Is this some sort of virus? And how can I solve this problem so windows stops showing this constant messages?

Heres a print screen:
[image]

Comment: Turn on show hidden and operating system files and search your PC. Where is that program located?

Comment: run ProcessExplorer and look for the command line of the tool isojounp.exe. Here you see where it is stored. Open the file properties and look at the details to see more about the exe.

Answer (score 1):

Since the application's filename does not show in internet searches, it might very well be malware that renames its files randomly. Try a thorough scan with [Kaspersky Free Virus Scan](http://www.kaspersky.com/free-virus-scan) and/or [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware Free](https://www.malwarebytes.org/downloads/), *in addition to your current real-time AV*.